# Python "In" Comparison with *$("!£*!'. characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, string-comparison

Seems while learning as I'm going with Python that I'm running into every little roadblock I can.

Even though this is a simply "if" I can't seem to get it to work, and i was wondering if its because my input (pgName) has full stops within the string. e.g com.android.driver.software.

In my example scenario, I will enter com.android.driver.software, what is listed within the Dict.value is com.android.driver.software.7 I thought using the comparison "in" would work in this instance, but it doesn't seem to be handling the logic at all.. What am i doing wrong?

```
pgName = raw_input("Please enter a package name e.g com.android.driver.software: ")

#while loop that checks user input from pgName to see if it matches any device
#listed in the JSON output and if so printing all the entires for that value.
while True:
    try:
        jdata = data["result"]["items"][y]["tagValues"]["IdDevicesMap"]["value"]
        for device in jdata.values():
            if pgName in device:
                print jdata[device]
                print " "
            else:
                print 'false'
```

When i run it everything is false.

Comment: Could you generate code that reproduces your problem but doesn't depend on as much setup, and is explicit about exactly how it relates to your question? For instance, provide *exact* values for both sides of the `in` operator -- that way anyone can copy-and-paste what would be only a few lines and see your problem, whereas right now to see your problem someone would need to have the same deep structure with an `IdDevicesMap`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for guidance on how to write a question that lets others see and reproduce your problem themselves, and thus enables folks to test their answers. (BTW, if you want to avoid downvotes or close votes while you're editing your question, if you delete it yourself you can undelete it later after edits).

Comment: mmm yup i could do that, give me a second. :-)

Comment: For instance, if what you expect is to look at whether `'com.android.driver.software' in 'com.android.driver.software.7'` is true, then the sample code can perform only (and precisely) that operation. If it doesn't reproduce your problem then written that way, then the problem is somewhere other than the content given in the question thus far, and some more debugging might be needed to ask a better question. (You might print the `repr()` form of your involved variables, to get exact values in a format you can reuse in code).

Comment: It seems like you're iterating the `values()` of the dict but then using the "pgName" value as a key in the lookup... Is that really what you mean to do? Could you provide what "jdata" actually contains?

Comment: yeah i see what you mean, however that's essentially all of the code the only thing i haven't included in the above is the JSON file with the values etc.. There isn't a problem in that as it reads it fine and i use it elsewhere in the code.

Comment: If your problem line is `if pgname in device:`, then check that `pgname` and `device` both contain what you expect -- either with a debugger, or by adding some extra print statements. Once you have an exact set of values that should work but don't (and that you've *tested* still don't work when you plug them into a REPL as constants), you can plug them into the question, and take out all the iterating-through-the-structure bits (that none of us can inspect or test since we don't have a copy of the structure).

Comment: @LexyStardust Yes, but device in the for in loop will pull the value out of the key and store it in device, then compare it with the user input which in this case is pgName.

Comment: @RubenBob, nevertheless, seeing the contents of `jdata` would help people trying to answer this question help. Any chance you can edit your post to include it?

Comment: @Charles Duffy I have checked that and they both contain exactly what i expect them to contain. It's really got me puzzled. The only difference between the two variables is a number at the end. However if input put the full line that matches the value of the DICT then it still returns false.

Comment: @LexyStardust, ...*grumble* about encouraging someone to fix the "Complete" and "Verifiable" parts of [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) by compromising "Minimal", rather than by making their code *even more* "Minimal" by simplifying.

Comment: @LexyStardust haha not a chance unfortunately, confidential business information.

Comment: @RubenBob, ...so, they contain exactly what you expect, so you can come up with a one-line reproducer that's just `print(x in y)`, printing `False` when it should be `True`, right?

Comment: is `device` a single `str` or a `list` or `str`s?

Comment: The more I read your code the more I'm betting you meant `for device in jdata.keys():`